# Couldn't start apache in xampp

Tags: php, apache, ssl

When I start `apache` through `xampp`, I get this error log:

> [Thu Nov 12 09:42:08.868102 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 3412:tid 244]
>   AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an
>   ID which matches the server name [Thu Nov 12 09:42:08.913105 2015]
>   [core:warn] [pid 3412:tid 244] AH00098: pid file
>   C:/xampp/apache/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of
>   previous Apache run? [Thu Nov 12 09:42:09.056113 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid
>   3412:tid 244] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does
>   NOT include an ID which matches the server name

I changed port in `httpd.conf` and `httpd-ssl.conf` but I still get this error.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you didn't properly configured the ssl file. Try following this [tutorial](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/ssl/ssl_howto.html).